# Why Hamiltonian for a Solid is periodic in Bloch Theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, crystals

It is as simple as the title and more general to Bloch theorem treatment. In any periodic infinite solid lattice, we say that the potential will be periodic. This makes sense, but how do we know that momentum/kinetic energy would also be periodic? Then only the Hamiltonian will be periodic with the periodicity of the lattice. The momentum operator is a differential operator which is abstract and you can't say what will be the end result of its operation on some vector.

Now there are few unconfirmed answers to this.

1. Energy Conservation. But I don't believe in this since I have read tunnelling
   which breaks energy conservation on our faces.
2. Spatial Invariance. Using the notion of the Noether theorem, one can say that since the space is invariant for these basis vectors, momentum would be conserved. But if I go on to see this in the Noether theorem, I would have to calculate Lagragian which I can construct from Hamiltonian. But I don't know how to go beyond that as we have a potential sitting there? Also, I don't exactly trust that we can simply use the classical Legendre transformation for Quantum Mechanics too.

Comment: Just a side comment for the second "unconfirmed answer" (spoiler: the answer is fundamentally wrong). A lattice has discrete translational invariance, meaning that momentum is not fully conserved, only up to a reciprocal lattice vector.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I wrote, "it is invariant for these basis vectors only".

Answer (score 5):

The momentum operator is, by definition, the generator of infinitesimal translations, and so must commute with all translations. In particular this includes lattice translations. The same goes for the kinetic energy operator, as it is promotional to the square of the momentum operator.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "All translations"? If I translate hydrogen atom wavefunction to a different radial point, momentum would not be the same, right? Hence, momentum would not commute.

Comment: A single hydrogen atom is hardly a periodic system…

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal T_{\mathbf a}$ be the operator which shifts the wavefunction by a vector $\mathbf a$, i.e. $\big(\mathcal T_{\mathbf a}\phi\big)(\mathbf x):=\phi(\mathbf x- \mathbf a)$.  It's not difficult to show that $\mathcal T_{\mathbf a}$ is unitary, and that $\big(\mathcal T_{\mathbf a}^\dagger \phi\big)(\mathbf x):= \phi(\mathbf x+\mathbf a)$.

The action of $\mathcal T_\mathbf a$ on the momentum operator $P:= -i\hbar \nabla$ is  $P \mapsto \mathcal T_\mathbf a P \mathcal T_\mathbf a^\dagger$. It's easy to see that
$$\big(\mathcal T_\mathbf a P \mathcal T_\mathbf a^\dagger \phi \big)(\mathbf x) = \big(\mathcal T_\mathbf a P \phi\big)(\mathbf x+\mathbf a) = T_\mathbf a \big(-i\hbar \nabla \phi\big)(\mathbf x+\mathbf a) = -i\hbar\nabla \phi(\mathbf x)$$

which means that $\mathcal T_\mathbf a P \mathcal T_\mathbf a^\dagger = P$ - in other words, the momentum operator is invariant under translations.  Similarly, $\mathcal T_\mathbf a P^2 \mathcal T_\mathbf a^\dagger = \big(\mathcal T_\mathbf a P \mathcal T_\mathbf a^\dagger \big)\big(\mathcal T_\mathbf a P \mathcal T_\mathbf a^\dagger\big)= P^2$, so the kinetic energy operator is also invariant under spatial translations.  Contrast this with the potential energy operator $\big(\mathcal V\phi\big)(\mathbf x) :=\phi(\mathbf x)V(\mathbf x)$:

$$\big(\mathcal T_\mathbf a \mathcal V \mathcal T_\mathbf a^\dagger \phi\big)(\mathbf x) = \big(\mathcal T_\mathbf a \mathcal V \phi\big)(\mathbf x-\mathbf a)= \big(\mathcal T_\mathbf a\phi\big)(\mathbf x-\mathbf a) V(\mathbf x-\mathbf a)= \phi(\mathbf x) V(\mathbf x-\mathbf a)$$
Therefore we have that $\mathcal T_\mathbf a \mathcal V \mathcal T_\mathbf a^\dagger \neq \mathcal V$; it is the operator which multiplies the wavefunction not by $V(\mathbf x)$, but rather by $V(\mathbf x-\mathbf a)$.

Putting all of this together, we see that

$$\mathcal T_\mathbf a \left(\frac{P^2}{2m} +\mathcal V\right)\mathcal T_\mathbf a^\dagger = \frac{P^2}{2m} + \mathcal T_\mathbf a \mathcal V \mathcal T_\mathbf a^\dagger$$

If the potential is indeed invariant under translation by $\mathbf a$ - so $V(\mathbf x-\mathbf a) = V(\mathbf x)$ - then the Hamiltonian is similarly invariant under such translations, and Bloch's theorem may be applied.